# Why is the main purpose of using the function "detach()"?

Tags: r

We were shown the following R code in class:

```
attach(LifeCycleSavings)
boxplot(sr, main = "Box Plot of Savings Ratio")
detach()
```

However, why would we need to use "detach()" here? I typed "LifeCycleSavings" and still got an output as follows:

```
> LifeCycleSavings
                  sr pop15 pop75     dpi  ddpi
Australia      11.43 29.35  2.87 2329.68  2.87
Austria        12.07 23.32  4.41 1507.99  3.93
Belgium        13.17 23.80  4.43 2108.47  3.82
```

The file "LifeCycleSavings" did not get detached.

Comment: Never, ever use `attach` or `detach`.  It's just bad practise and isn't necessary.

Comment: The only use I've ever had for those functions has been if I'm using R _only_ interactively and with essentially only one data set. Maybe some people do that often, but I don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your specific question, `detach` in this context is removing that data frame from the search path. This means that you can no longer refer to variable names alone from that data frame:

```
attach(LifeCycleSavings)
> sr
 [1] 11.43 12.07 13.17  5.75 12.88  8.79  0.60 11.90  4.98 10.78 16.85  3.59 11.24 12.64 12.55 10.67  3.01
[18]  7.70  1.27  9.00 11.34 14.28 21.10  3.98 10.35 15.48 10.25 14.65 10.67  7.30  4.44  2.02 12.70 12.78
[35] 12.49 11.14 13.30 11.77  6.86 14.13  5.13  2.81  7.81  7.56  9.22 18.56  7.72  9.24  8.89  4.71
> detach(LifeCycleSavings)
> sr
Error: object 'sr' not found
```

So at this point if we wanted to use `sr` we'd need to type `LifeCycleSavings$sr` in order to tell R where to look.

As Andrie mentioned, many people frown on this sort of use of `attach` and `detach` (although `detach` is sometimes also used for removing packages from the search path) because it can really clutter up your search path.

Comment: @hadley Care to elaborate...?

Comment: No one cares about the search path; the bigger problems are the lack of symmetry with assignment, and verbose/explicit is usually better than implicit.

Comment: @hadley Fair enough, but I have a hard time believing that _no one_ thinks it's a problem if you attach a data frame with a column name that's identical to some other object you've defined in your workspace. That will certainly cause problems for a naive user attaching lots of data frames.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misinterpreted your comment about the search path - I thought you were complaining about the length of `search()`, but you're complaining about the length of `lapply(search(), ls))` (I don't think I'd call that the search path, but I don't know a better name)

Comment: See also `searchpaths()` which is definitely not what you mean